# call module into another module

Tags: r, shiny

I want to display a dataframe when a button is clicked.
I create a mod for the button and a mod for the dataframe. In the *mod_button_server* function i call *mod_dataframe_server* where I create the dataframe and assign it to output

**mod_button.R**

```
mod_button_ui <- function(id){ ns <- NS(id); tagList(
    actionButton(ns("button"), id) )}

mod_button_server <- function(id){ moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){ns <- session$ns
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      print(id)
      mod_dataframe_server("table")
    })})}
```

**mod_dataframe.R**

```
mod_dataframe_ui <- function(id){ ns <- NS(id); tagList(
    tableOutput(ns("mytable")))}

mod_dataframe_server <- function(id){moduleServer(id, function(input, output,session){ ns <- session$ns;
    df <- data.frame(Years = seq(2000, 2009), Colonne2 = rnorm(10), Colonne3 = rnorm(10), Colonne4 = rnorm(10))
    output$mytable <- renderTable({df})})}
```

**app_ui.R**

```
app_ui <- function(request) {tagList(golem_add_external_resources(),
    mod_button_ui("B1"), #mod_button_ui("B2"),
    mod_dataframe_ui("table"),
  )}
```

**app_server.R**

```
app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mod_button_server("B1") #mod_button_server("B2")}
```

Comment: ... and your problem is?  How does the actual behaviour differ from the desired behaviour?  Do you see any warning or error messages?  If so, what are they and where are they reported?  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a *minimal reproducible* example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Also, `mod_dataframe_server("table")` should probably be `mod_dataframe_server(ns("table"))`, but without a MRE it's difficult to be sure.

Comment: Hello, @Limey, i don't have any warning or error. The code I shared is reproducible, I don't understand what I need to modify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

You can output a data frame from `mod_dataframe_server` like this:

```r
mod_dataframe_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    df <- data.frame(Years = seq(2000, 2009),
                     Colonne2 = rnorm(10),
                     Colonne3 = rnorm(10),
                     Colonne4 = rnorm(10))
    return(df)
  })
}
```

Which can then be accessed in `mod_button_server` like this:

```r
mod_button_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns

    observeEvent(input$button, {
      df1 <- mod_dataframe_server(ns("mytable"))
      output$table <- renderTable(df1)
    })
  })
}
```

`mod_dataframe_ui` can stay as the default Golem template since it doesn't need to be called. Displaying the table takes place in `mod_button_ui`:

```r
mod_button_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("button"), label = "Click"),
    tableOutput(ns("table"))
  )
}
```

The app server function is the same as in your attempt, and `app_ui` looks like this:

```r
app_ui <- function(request) {
  tagList(
    golem_add_external_resources(),
    fluidPage(
      mod_button_ui("B1"),
    )
  )
}
```

### Option 2

Alternatively, you could use just the button module and remove the dataframe module.
Meaning `mod_button_server` would use [`observe()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shiny/versions/1.7.5/topics/observe) and [`bindEvent()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shiny/versions/1.7.5/topics/bindEvent) to create and refresh the table upon pressing the button.
`mod_button_ui`, `app_ui`, and `app_server` are the same as in the first option.

```r
mod_button_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns

    observe({
      output$table <- renderTable(
        data.frame(Years = seq(2000, 2009),
                   Colonne2 = rnorm(10),
                   Colonne3 = rnorm(10),
                   Colonne4 = rnorm(10))
      )
    }) |> bindEvent(input$button)
  })
}
```

## Working Example

This implements option 2 from above. Option 1 is included, but I've commented it out.

```r
library(shiny)

mod_dataframe_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    df <- data.frame(Years = seq(2000, 2009),
                     Colonne2 = rnorm(10),
                     Colonne3 = rnorm(10),
                     Colonne4 = rnorm(10))
    return(df)
  })
}

mod_button_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    
    # option 1
    # observeEvent(input$button, {
    #   df1 <- mod_dataframe_server(ns("mytable"))
    #   output$table <- renderTable(df1)
    # })

    # option 2
    observe({
      output$table <- renderTable(
        data.frame(Years = seq(2000, 2009),
                   Colonne2 = rnorm(10),
                   Colonne3 = rnorm(10),
                   Colonne4 = rnorm(10))
      )
    }) |> bindEvent(input$button)
  })
}

mod_button_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("button"), label = "Click"),
    tableOutput(ns("table"))
  )
}

app_ui <- function(request) {
  tagList(
    fluidPage(
      mod_button_ui("B1"),
    )
  )
}

app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mod_button_server("B1") 
}

shinyApp(
  ui = app_ui,
  server = app_server
)
```

Comment: I believe this is a good answer, but it could be made even better by providing complete, reproducible code for both options.  We ask those who ask questions to provide MREs, so it's only fair to do the same in reply.

Comment: Hello @steven314, thank for your help. If I have several buttons, how can I only have a single Output table where the dataframes will be displayed? When I click on button 1 it displays a dataframe in output$table, if I click on button 2 it displays another dataframe which replaces the one present in output$table.

Comment: @dia05, this might be better suited for its own question, but you can add another `actionButton` in `mod_button_ui` and add another `observe({...}) |> bindEvent(input$button2)` block to assign a different data frame to `output$table`.

Comment: @Steven314, thank, I have sucessfully done it.
I have one last question. Is it possible to separate each part? if I want to separate the dataframe part to make it a module, how can I do it? I would like to put `tableOutput` and the dataframe creation part in a separate module.

Comment: @dia05, sorry for the delay. I tried playing around with that originally. I could not find a solution to that specifically. It is definitely possible to do the dataframe creation in its own module, since a module is just a function and can return a value (see option 1 in my answer). But to display the table **and** handle dataframe creation in the same module, I don't see a way that is possible. My understanding is that it would be better to call the necessary dataframe creation module, and then display it using the parent module (`mod_button_ui` in this case).